# How to configure two firewalls for two WANs and one LAN

Tags: routing, router, nat, local-area-network, dmz

I have two WANs with static IPs:

1. DSL (PPPoA)
2. Fibre (Ethernet through fibre media converter)

So far I was using one firewall Vigor2830Vn to handle traffic from both WAN ports. But I need to be able to restart it from the internet in case it becomes unresponsive. I thought of adding an additional firewall between Wan2 and the firewall, one to which I can login from the internet, e.g. pfSense SG-2220. I thought of replacing Vigor completely but then I would need to buy a separate DSL modem as well as WiFi gateway - both are handled by the Vigor router currently.

Anyway, the topology would be like this:

```
   PPPoA      Fibre
 StaticIP1  StaticIP2
    |          WAN
    |        pfSense
    |          LAN
    |           |
   Wan1       Wan2
     Vigor2830Vn
         LAN
          |
```

In other words, WAN2 of Vigor would be connected to LAN of pfSense.

An alternative topology could be:

```
   PPPoA            Fibre
 StaticIP1        StaticIP2
    |                WAN
    |              pfSense
    |                LAN
   Wan1      Wan2     |
    Vigor2830Vn       |
         LAN-----------
          |
         LAN
```

Thus connecting LAN port of pfSense directly to one of the free LAN ports in Vigor (which should then work as a switch bridging traffic from both WAN ports).

Now questions. Is there a standard way of connecting multiple routers one after another like this? I heard of DMZ or DMZ Host but I think they would not apply here.

In the first topology, how can I access the web interface of pfSense from LAN? The traffic would need to go through Wan2 of Vigor. If pfSense's LAN interface was assigned a local IP (e.g. 10.0.0.1) Vigor would not pass the local traffic through Wan2 to pfSense. And I can't assign a public IP since it may be routed through the other router.

In the second topology, how would the traffic from LAN be routed to the internet? I guess it would depend on the Gateway set up on each computer in LAN (i.e. it would be either the local IP of Vigor or pfSense). Would any load-balancing or failover be possible?

Comment: How do you intend to restart the device if it is unresponsive? I don't see any device to perform remote power cycling in your diagrams.

Comment: Yeah, it's not relevant to the question so I omitted it. I have IP Power 9255 which I can plug to one of the LAN interfaces.